# How can I install/embed Google Project Sunroof on my site?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, iframe

I tried to create a form where users  fill the street address field/element on my form,  I want that data to fill this form https://sunroof.withgoogle.com with that same address, submit, retrieve and then display the resulting submission data within my forms submission window for reference and manipulation. Two examples of this are: https://roofingcalculator.com/ and https://estimate.sunstorm.energy/get-estimate/

I searched and could not find an API to do this with and I'm not tech savvy enough to go another route without instructions. I also tried to embed the page within my own page, but couldn't get that to work, either.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: here is the sunroof API information location as of now: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/solar?hl=en you may also want to search the forms for other related questions you may have here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-solar-api